# How to print the entire function containing a matched string using Powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell

I need to find a certain string in a .java file and select only the function containing the string.

Example code:

```
/*    */ package com.mypackage.servlets;

/*    */ import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
/*    */ import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


/*    */ public class GetChallengeServlet
/*    */   extends HttpServlet
/*    */ {

            public  int hello(){

            }

/*    */   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest paramHttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse paramHttpServletResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {}
/*    */   
/* 22 */   String userName = null;
/*    */ 
            public  int hello2(){

            }
/*    */   
/*    */   public void service(HttpServletRequest paramHttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse paramHttpServletResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {
/* 26 */     this.userName = null;
/* 27 */     String str1 = null;
/* 28 */     String str2 = null;
/* 29 */     HttpSession httpSession = paramHttpServletRequest.getSession(false);
/* 30 */     PrintWriter printWriter = null;

/*    */   }
/*    */ }
```

1. I need to recursively print the entire function which has parameter "HttpServletRequest"
2. I need to recursively print the entire function which has string "getSession"

i.e Here, I need to print "doGet" and "service" functions only.

Can I achieve this using any advanced regex? 
Any other logic to achieve the same?

Actually I need to code in Powershell, Bash, and Python. I hope the solution will work for all the languages.

I tried below Powershell

```
$input = gc -Raw 'GetChallengeServlet.java'
$sections = $input | select-string -AllMatches '(?smi)(public.*\(HttpServlet.*?(public|private|protected))'
$sections.Matches | foreach {$_.Value}
```

But it selects :

```
public class GetChallengeServlet
/*    */   extends HttpServlet
/*    */ {

            public  int hello(){

            }

/*    */   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest paramHttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse paramHttpServletResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {}
/*    */   
/* 22 */   String userName = null;
/*    */ 
            public
```

This is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. I need to recursively print the entire function which has parameter
>      "HttpServletRequest"

This regex will work for your example ([view result](https://regex101.com/r/d7jmxW/1)):

```
public.*?HttpServletRequest(?s).*?{.*?}
```

> 2. I need to recursively print the entire function which has string
>      "getSession"

This regex will work for your example ([view result](https://regex101.com/r/msECUx/1)):

```
public\s(?!class)(?s)[^}]+{[^}]+getSession[^}]+}
```

As I pointed out, these regexes will work for your example. They probably won't work anymore if your code gets more complex, like containing nested code blocks inside your functions.

You get very close to parsing, if you want the regex to be ready for every possible code snippet inside your functions. You will have to find balanced parantheses and more. In my opinion that would be an overkill for your problem. You should probably use a parser that separates all functions and then you can go with regexes to identifiy only the desired functions.

---

Example how to use the regexes in PowerShell:

```bsh
$content = Get-Content .\GetChallengeServlet.java -Raw
Select-String -InputObject $content -Pattern 'public.*?HttpServletRequest(?s).*?{.*?}' -AllMatches | ForEach-Object {$_.Matches.Value}
```

Output:

```java
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest paramHttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse paramHttpServletResponse) t
hrows ServletException, IOException {}
public void service(HttpServletRequest paramHttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse paramHttpServletResponse)
 throws ServletException, IOException {
/* 26 */     this.userName = null;
/* 27 */     String str1 = null;
/* 28 */     String str2 = null;
/* 29 */     HttpSession httpSession = paramHttpServletRequest.getSession(false);
/* 30 */     PrintWriter printWriter = null;

/*    */   }
```

---

Tip to proceed further for more complex examples, instead of really parsing the java source code, you could do a workaround like this: Split your files into pieces (by script of course)

1. Split before every class definition, if your files may contain multiple class definitions
2. For each class piece, split before each method definition

After that, you will more or less have only single methods and won't have to determine their ends anymore. Then you can filter them by the regexes provided above.

There will still be a challenge: What about methods, that are nested inside methods? Will you have to care about them? It will get even more complicated...

Comment: This doesn't work for Powershell regex. So regex differ for each language?

Comment: Also it doesn't work when multiple "{}" are there. The regex will stop when it sees first "}"

Comment: I know it doesn't work for all cases, that's what I described as nested code and looking for balanced parantheses. That's what you have to do to find the end of a function. All in all you get very close to parsing and I would not recommend to reinvent the wheel in this situation.

Comment: And I added an example on how these regexes work in PowerShell.